# what's the memory layout of a Class if it contains Containers such as std::map, in VC compiler

Tags: c++, stl, containers, destructor

```
ClassA{
public:
std::map<int,int> m_map;
...
...
};
```

I've tried the `/d1reportSingleClassLayout` in visual studio but cannot really decode the output:

```
1> 0 | ?$map@HHU?$less@H@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBHH@std@@@2@ m_map
1>28 | ......
```

My understating is that containers are not fixed in size, so in the memory layout of Obj of ClassA, there should exists a pointer pointing to actual m_map content in the heap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The precise layout of your `std::map` implementation is down to the people who wrote your standard library. It is not defined by C++.

You could investigate the standard headers on your build machine, or you could simply forget about it and code to standard APIs instead.

But, yes, there will be a pointer or two in there somewhere, pointing to dynamically allocated memory. Potentially quite a lot of it.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your questions:

1. **Will there be a pointer pointing to m_map in the heap?** That is a question only the makers of `std::map` can answer. I would say yes, but you'd have to look at the implementation of `map` to find that, ultimately. In order for the map to grow dynamically there would have to be a pointer.
2. **Will the default destructor of Class A automatically free the space allocated to m_map?** Yes, they were designed with that in mind so the programmer didn't have to worry about memory. However, the method in which it does this is also in the implementation of `std::map`.

I think it's wise to not worry about this too much. The API was designed to alleviate the worries you mention.

Comment: Well, it's impossible for there _not_ to be a pointer in there somewhere. In some form, at least.

Comment: I agree, I just hate to give absolute judgments like that when I'm not sure. It doesn't make sense for no pointers to exist.

Comment: So when destructing Obj of ClassA, ClassA's destructor is invoked first, then the m_map destructor. But, if the pointer to m_map is dectructed, how can we destruct m_map then?

Comment: There's no pointer to `m_map`. `m_map` contains a pointer to something else.